# Django create a models.ManyToMany and models.ForeignKey to the same table

Tags: python, django

All,
I'm trying to configure my Django models.py file to include 2 tables with a ManyToMany and a ForeignKey link between the 2.  The current configuration with only one entry works fine:

```
Current models.py file:

from django.db import models

class CustTeamMembers(models.Model):
    member_first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    member_last_name  = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    member_email      = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    member_phone      = models.CharField(max_length = 25, blank=True)

    class Meta(object):
        ordering = ['member_last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.member_first_name + ' ' + self.member_last_name

class CustTeamName(models.Model):
    cust_name    = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    cust_members = models.ManyToManyField(CustTeamMembers, blank=True)
    cust_meet    = models.CharField(max_length = 40, blank=True)
    cust_status  = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cust_name

    def get_members(self):
        return ", ".join([str(p) for p in self.cust_members.all()])
```

I would like to add another field above the "cust_members" entry.  The reason for this is I have teams with multiple members and one of them is the lead for the team.  I tried the following, but it failed:

```
Alternate models.py file:

from django.db import models

class CustTeamMembers(models.Model):
    member_first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    member_last_name  = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    member_email      = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    member_phone      = models.CharField(max_length = 25, blank=True)

    class Meta(object):
        ordering = ['member_last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.member_first_name + ' ' + self.member_last_name

class CustTeamName(models.Model):
    cust_name    = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    cust_lead    = models.ForeignKey(CustTeamMembers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    cust_members = models.ManyToManyField(CustTeamMembers, blank=True)
    cust_meet    = models.CharField(max_length = 40, blank=True)
    cust_status  = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cust_name

    def get_members(self):
        return ", ".join([str(p) for p in self.cust_members.all()])
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this?
~Ed

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I can't even get past the ~save~ routine.  I get this error:

Comment: I can't even get past the ~save~ routine. I get this error:  ERRORS:  custdat.CustTeamName.cust_lead:  (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'CustTeamName.cust_lead' clashes with reverse accessor for 'CustTeamName.cust_mambers'.  HINT:  Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'CustTeamName.cust_lead' or 'CustTeamName.cust_mambers'.  Then the error is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using foreignkey the same column will be referred in another model

class CustTeamName(models.Model):

```
 member_first_name    = models.ForeignKey(CustTeamMembers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

Comment: Let me see if I can sort this out a little better:  A customer lead is a entry of the customer team members.  This person can also be a lead in other teams, or just a team member or no relation to other teams.  That is the relationship I'm trying to code here.  I don't know if this helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

Django offers the ManyToMany `through` property, allowing extra data on the relation.

```
from django.db import models

class CustTeamMember(models.Model):
    member_first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    member_last_name  = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    member_email      = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    member_phone      = models.CharField(max_length = 25, blank=True)

    class Meta(object):
        ordering = ['member_last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.member_first_name + ' ' + self.member_last_name

class CustTeamName(models.Model):
    cust_name    = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    cust_members = models.ManyToManyField(CustTeamMembers, through="CustTeamThrough" blank=True)
    cust_meet    = models.CharField(max_length = 40, blank=True)
    cust_status  = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cust_name

    def get_members(self):
        return ", ".join([str(p) for p in self.cust_members.all()])



class CustTeamThrough(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(CustTeamMember, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(CustTeamName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_leader = models.models.BooleanField(default=False)
```